# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlComment' to type 'System.Xml.XmlElement'.'

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I have a Winform application and I am getting the following error. Could you please help me how to solve it.

```
    public class ChangeLanguage
    {
        public void UpdateConfig(string key, string value)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

            foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xmlElement.Name.Equals("appSettings"))
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xmlElement.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value.Equals(key))
                        {
                            xNode.Attributes[1].Value = value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

            xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that error appears in the code you provided ?
It doesnt look like.

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/ayrqyd6 This is screen shot

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML (XDocument etc) instead of XmlDocument. It's a much better API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conversion error.
If you want to iterate and do some actions only for XmlElement objects, then you have to check for that type with use of `OfType` (since no linq is available).
In your example the solution could look like it:

```
public class ChangeLanguage
{
    public void UpdateConfig(string key, string value)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

       foreach (var xmlElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.OfType<XmlElement>())
       {
            if (xmlElement.Name.Equals("appSettings"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode xNode in xmlElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value.Equals(key))
                    {
                        xNode.Attributes[1].Value = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Using `GetType()` isn't a good idea here - it means if there's a subclass for some reason, you'll miss it. Simpler *and* more reliable would be `foreach (var xmlElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.OfType<XmlElement>())`

Comment: Note that `OfType` is an extension method on `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, so it *is* available.

Comment: @Bartosz Olchowik Didn't accept definitions: https://www.hizliresim.com/6yu4vx5

Comment: @Berkancelik2: Using `OfType` *would* compile, as then the type would still be `XmlElement`. But as I said in the comments on the question, I'd recommend using LINQ to XML instead. Or if you want to use this answer, you *could* just cast `xmlElement` to `XmlElement`, e.g. `var element = (XmlElement) xmlElement` - after the type check.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks this answer worked. I'm not getting any errors

Comment: @JonSkeet jon I'm going to ask you a question about windows form. Do you have any idea about how I can do localization in the best way? Sources etc. can you throw

Comment: @Berkancelik2: That's not an appropriate use of Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet didnt know about OfType functionality.
Thank you for sharing your knowledge, and i totally agree with you.